# Yielding with For-loop and pass to match-case Expression

Tags: scala, for-loop

I was experimenting with the following code;

```
(for (f <- (new File(".")).listFiles() if !f.isDirectory) yield f) match {
  case x:File => println(x.getAbsoluteFile)
  case _ => println(_)
}
```

Obviously I am wrong somehow, as I am getting the following Error

```
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : java.io.File
 required: Array[java.io.File]
    case x:File => println(x.getAbsoluteFile)
           ^
```

What I was trying to do is pretty obvious; I tried to get each yielded value from the for-loop and pass it to a match-case "filter". I am not interesting in writing a better File tree filter rather than knowing the reason of the Error that I am getting and if it is possible to fix it (or rewrite somehow else).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few symbols away:

```
for (f <- (new File(".")).listFiles() if !f.isDirectory) f match {
  case x:File => println(x.getAbsoluteFile)
  case _ => println(_)
}
```

The diff is

```
yield f)
{ f
```

In your case you're first processing (listing|filtering|yielding one-by-one) whole collection and only then match whole result.